# Chrome GUI not showing in IIS windows server

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, iis

I have a Django web scrapping project that is using Selenium and Chromedriver. Everything works fine and I tested multiple times on the local host .

The problem is when I run that through my IIS server in a Windows operating system , its working in the task manager but not showing GUI. I also tested that code on that windows server using :

`python manage.py runserver`

And that was showing chrome GUI in that server local host also . So the only problem is when I run it through the IIS . How to solve this problem? Is that about security permissions?

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Naturally the result of Windows session isolation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LexLi Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You cannot escape from a Windows core feature, but there might be ways to modify your application to play well with it. Since this requires thorough review of your setup, you'd better hire an experienced consultant.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, please check if there are any relevant error messages in the Event Viewer or console.

Comment: @samwu I’ve checked . There isnt any

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.